# Selenium (C#) Chrome driver: the pages loading is not managed as before since the version 77 of the Chrome web driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

It seems that something has been modified since the version 77 of the Chrome driver.
Some tests are not working anymore whereas my code has not been updated.

When the test is running it seems that it is not waiting for the pages loading anymore.
In version 76 of the Chrome driver the pages loading was correctly and automatically managed by Selenium.

I reproduce this issue with the Chrome webdriver version 77 and 78.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common for timing-sensitive behavior to change between Chromedriver versions. In general, I've found that I need to insert some type of wait/sleep before the failing code, typically after a previous simulated user action such as a Click(), to fix these. Standard Selenium advice seems to be to only add waits which wait for a specific condition, but IME it's been difficult, unreliable, and requires large amounts of additional code to determine and program waits for specific conditions which actually solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Right now I've disabled the auto updates of Chrome and keep the the webdriver v76 to avoid this issue.